# How to implement my sql statement in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following MySQL query which works fine. It returns Random results from my table.

```
SET @prev=0,@rownum=0;
SELECT utilizador_id, nome 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         IF( @prev <> utilizador_id, 
             @rownum := 1, 
             @rownum := @rownum+1 
         ) AS rank, 
         @prev := utilizador_id, 
         @rownum  
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM anuncios 
    ORDER BY utilizador_id, rand()
  ) AS random_ads
) AS ads_ranked 
WHERE rank <= 2;
```

**Here is my table:**

```
+-------------+------+
|utilizador_id|nome  |
+-------------+------|
|     1       |test1 |
|     1       |test2 |
|     1       |test3 |
|     1       |test4 |
|     1       |test5 |
|     2       |test1 |
|     2       |test2 |
|     2       |test3 |
|     3       |test1 |
|     3       |test2 |
|     3       |test3 |
+-------------+------|
```

**Expected Random results:**

```
+-------------+------+
|utilizador_id|nome  |
+-------------+------|
|     1       |test2 |
|     1       |test5 |
|     2       |test1 |
|     2       |test2 |
|     3       |test1 |
|     3       |test3 |
+-------------+------|
```

The sql statement as mention works fine in MySQL but I want to implement it in my Laravel environment.

**My Question:** How do I implement this sql statement in Laravel?

Comment: @maytham - Doesn't seem so to me, either way, it was a bad answer. You can't tell me that, from the question as it currently stands, that a raw DB query is the answer. No idea whether or not he is using Eloquent, no idea what his issue actually is and furthermore, for a rough punt, I'd say his issue is more that he simply needs to use **FooModel::orderBy('utilizador_id')->orderBy('updated_at')->get()** than a raw SQL call.
Simply put, bad answer = downvote whether or not you think it's unfair, I don't care. SO needs high quality answers, not lazy point score hoping.

Comment: @DanWhite after a little thinking I do only agree, therefore I deleted my answer, the other challenge is he do not reply to any thing since 6 jul. :)

Comment: @maytham coolio. Also apprars to have a -8 score for an identical(ish) question

Comment: Here is a fresh answer to this question. This answer is tested and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by using `DB::statement`, `DB:raw` and `DB::select`.

The code is tested on my Laravel 5.0 test environment and it works perfectly.

Your mysql statement is also tested it works perfectly on MySQL console.

**Here is the code:**

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @prev=0,@rownum=0'));

$results =
    DB::select(
        DB::raw("
          SELECT utilizador_id, nome
          FROM (
            SELECT *,
                 IF( @prev <> utilizador_id,
                     @rownum := 1,
                     @rownum := @rownum+1
                 ) AS rank,
                 @prev := utilizador_id,
                 @rownum
            FROM (
              SELECT * FROM `anuncios`
              ORDER BY utilizador_id, rand()
            ) AS random_ads
          ) AS ads_ranked
          WHERE rank <= 2;
        ")
    );
```

**View results**

```
echo "utilizador_id | nome <br />";

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    echo $result->utilizador_id . "__________| " . $result->nome . "<br />";
}
```

**Remember** to added `use DB;` after the name space:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
```

I have made View results code only to demonstrate all results output, but it is up to you how to manipulate the data in your code.

**Test results**

**Random results of your mysql statement in MySQL console**
[image: Random results from MySQL]

**Random results of your mysql statement in Laravel**
[image: Random results in Laravel]

**Note:**

1- I have solved this question my self for you but I faced a little issue and I got input from Kryptonit3 in Laracast forum.

2- You might find other solutions to this question or it can be solved in different ways, but I have chosen to solve this way.

The full question and answer in Note 1, can be found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/db-raw).