# Why to use DB::raw inside DB::select in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is it mandatory to use the function `DB::raw` when you are running a query and you are not using the fluent query builder in Laravel?

e.g.

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users");

$result2 = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users"));
```

I get the same result in both cases. So why is it necessary to use `DB::raw`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `DB::raw()` is used to make arbitrary SQL commands which aren't parsed
>   any further by the query builder. They therefore can [create a vector
>   for attack](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#raw-expressions) via SQL injection.

Check this ref. link, with more details: http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256943/how-to-implement-my-sql-statement-in-laravel/31529886#31529886) of `DB::raw` and `DB::select`

Comment: So in my example I guess that the query with DB::raw is faster since laravel doesn't check or validate anything.

Comment: I will say yes, you can assume/conclude that, in some case like this example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410909/laravel-create-trigger-from-migration/27418738#27418738) you can use `DB::raw` alone if the sql statement is only for internal use. and you are sure of is content.